# SUMPRODUCT in Excel using cell references

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have this rather inelegant excel 2010 formula for counting the number of instances that occur within a certain range (of 1 to 5 days in this case), but it works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*('Defect List'!$D$2:$D$999="Closed")*
(NETWORKDAYS('Defect List'!$C$2:$C$999+0,'Defect List'!$J$2:$J$999+0)>=1)) 
- SUMPRODUCT(1*
(NETWORKDAYS('Defect List'!$C$2:$C$999+0,'Defect List'!$J$2:$J$999+0)>5)
)
```

Q: Now I want to parameterise it by replacing the 1 and the 5 with cells M3 and N3. But I can't seem to get the syntax right - can anyone help please?

Comment: Why does `$M$3` and `$N$3` not work when you sub it in. What error are you getting?

Comment: If I use `M3` and `N3` or `$M$3` and `$N$3`, the answer comes to 0 where it was previously 99! I thought I could use `">="&M3`or something like that, but that reports an error.

Comment: Replace with M3 and N3 and hit F2 and see if they are highlighted

Answer (score 2):

The `*` in your formula will be throwing the error, replace it with a comma so it looks like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*('Defect List'!$D$2:$D$999="Closed"),
            1*(NETWORKDAYS('Defect List'!$C$2:$C$999+0,
                           'Defect List'!$J$2:$J$999+0)>=M3),
            1*(NETWORKDAYS('Defect List'!$C$2:$C$999+0,
                           'Defect List'!$J$2:$J$999+0)<=N3))
```

You can do it all in one sumproduct, but a `COUNTIFS` would be a better solution, if you put the `NETWORKDAYS` into a column in Defect List, say AZ:

```
=COUNTIFS('Defect List'!$D$2:$D$999,"Closed",
          'Defect List'!$AZ$2:$AZ$999,">="&$M$3,
          'Defect List'!$AZ$2:$AZ$999,"<="&$N$3)
```

This means excel won't have to recalculate each `NETWORKDAYS` for every cell.

Comment: @DTS...thank you! Apologies for the delay, I will try this soon.